# Trouble with header file

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl, debian

I got the following error on compiling a c code I wrote. I understand that the problem is in the header file. Can anyone please tell me which all header files are needed to define these functions.

```
sign.c: In function ‘main’:
sign.c:78: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/tmp/ccnsSeHy.o: In function `sign_data_evp':
sign.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `check_ssl_rv'
sign.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `check_ssl_rv'
sign.c:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to `check_ssl_rv'
/tmp/ccnsSeHy.o: In function `main':
sign.c:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `initialize'
sign.c:(.text+0x1d6): undefined reference to `select_engine'
sign.c:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to `sign_data'
sign.c:(.text+0x216): undefined reference to `clean_engine'
sign.c:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `clean_up'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The header files that I have used so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#ifdef __VMS
#include <socket.h>
#include <inet.h>

#include <in.h>
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

Operating platform: Linux
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You understand it wrong. It does not complain about unknown function prototype, it complains during the linking. So you probably forgot to link with some library or some object file.

Comment: I tried to compile it using `gcc -o sample -lssl -lcrypt sample.c`
Which other library should I link to compile these functions?

Comment: @binish Usually the `-lssl` is missing, or the path to the libs is not set correctly.

Comment: Try `gcc -o sample sample.c -lcrypto -lssl`. The order of libs and sources matters. The latter must resolve the symbols of modules/libs specified before. Not vice versa.

Comment: I have compiled other programs using `-lssl` and `-lcrypt`. so that is  not the problem. @mity: that doesnot seem to work too.

Comment: I'm not sitting at the linux box right now but still: Place the `-l...` options after the source ones. It's the libs which provide the missing symbols to the `sample.c`, not vice versa.

Comment: @mity: I have tried it. Still no hope. And usually my other codes compiled both ways. But this one doesnot seem to work.

Comment: Well, you can also have some problem with the libraries (are the libs at standard places providing the symbols `check_ssl_rv`, `initialize` etc.?

Comment: Anyway the listed error in the question means: I cannot link because I do not see where `check_ssl_rv` as well as the other listed symbols are implemented. It's not related to headers at all.

Comment: check_ssl_rv is in the openssl API. Is there abother ssl lib in `/usr/lib/*ssl*`? And where are the openssl libs? Not in /usr/local/openssl/lib?

Comment: Yes but.... Add `-Wl,-v` into the linking command, it will list default library search paths. Then looks for first dir where `libssl.so` exists, and check with `nm` it reallu exports the symbols which the linker does not see.

Comment: `gcc -Wl,-v ....` propagates `-v` (verbose) option to the linker, which then will write more info, including where it looks for the libraries. Use that to find out from what directory the `libssl.so` is actually used. Then using utility `nm /some/path/lib` you can get list of functions a library exports. This allows you to verify you link with `libssl.so` from the right dir, and that that particular library has the symbol `check_ssl_rv`.

Answer (score 0):

try with this 
gcc sslprogname.c -o sslprogname -Wl,-Bstatic -lssl -Wl,-Bdynamic -lssl3 -lcrypto.It worked for me