# Libraries required to compile certain functions

Tags: c, linux, openssl, debian

I have used these functions inside a program: `check_ssl_rv`,`initialize`,`select_engine`,`sign_data`, `clean_engine`,`clean_up`
Then I compiled it using `gcc -o opname codename.c`
But it showed a lots of errors. I understood that it is due to the absence of certain linked libraries when I browsed the web.
So I changed the compilation command to `gcc -o opname codename.c -lssl -lcrypt -lpthread`. But again on compiling the above functions showed errors like `sign.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to 'check_ssl_rv'`
Then I found the following link from stackoverflow itself:
[`Trouble with header file`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135178/trouble-with-header-file)
But it does not provide a valid solution. Can anyone tell me which all libraries to link for compiling a code with the above functions. Thanks in advance. The operating platform is linux.

Comment: What does `pkg-config --list-all | grep openssl` show?

Comment: `openssl                        OpenSSL - Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries and tools`

Comment: Can any one help? I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: If you link a library you not only need the "normal" library you also need the according "-devel" in fedora and "-dev" in ubuntu library.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a standard lib, you need to get the library file from the provider(may come along with the headers), then compile with your source file together.